# iOSにおける無音カメラアプリの実装方法について

Tags: swift, ios, iphone

アプリからのシャッター音の消音方法について質問させていただきます。
世の中にある無音カメラでは、ほとんどの場合カメラをビデオモードで起動してキャプチャするという方法を取っているかと思いますが、これでは最大でも1920x1080の画像しか取得できません。
しかし、中には高解像度でかつ無音のカメラ(Microsoft Pixのようなもの）もあります。
これらのアプリではどのように無音を実現しているのでしょうか、プライベートAPIを使用しているのでしょうか。
ご教授お願いします。

Comment: @OOPer 静かなところで撮影する状況は他にもいろいろあると思います。それはとても失礼な発言ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 「静かなところで撮影する状況は他にもいろいろある」のは百も承知でAppleはスチル写真の撮影を無音化できないようにしています。表現を失礼と感じられる方がおられるのであれば、謝らなければいけませんが、海外でアプリについての話をする際に「日本製カメラアプリは皆盗撮用」と言うイメージを持っている方は非常に多かったので、なぜそれが必要かについてご説明いただいた方が良いだろうと言う気持ちは変わりません。

Comment: 誤解を招く質問の仕方で申し訳ないです。
質問の意図は単純な「技術的興味」です。いろいろ調べても、「ビデオモードでキャプチャする」とか「シャッター音を逆位相にして再生して相殺する」などイマイチピンとくる回答がなく、一体Microsoft Pixはどうやってシャッター音を消してるのだろう？？と不思議に思っておりました。

Comment: @mktst さん、誤解を招いていたのは私のコメントの方だと思いますが、おそらくかなり多数の方が私の最初のコメントの後半のような感じ方をするであろうと思われましたので、目的をご説明いただいた方が良いだろうと思った次第です。失礼に感じられた部分がありましたらご容赦ください。